# Variable selection when dependant variable is a clinical score

Tags: multivariate-analysis, model-selection

I am building a mixed linear model to evaluate the effect of a particuliar variable on the evolution of a clinical score over time.
The clinical score is calculated via an equation using the age, a blood mesure and the sex of the subject.

My question is : can I adjust my model on these 3 predictors ? 
I feel like adjusting on the predictors which served to built the dependant variable could cause important bias.

Thank for your responses.